# how to delete selected data from local storage on flutter using swipe

Tags: flutter, dart

I was working on my flutter app and everything worked fine for me but now when I'm deleting notes by swipe after reload they come back and I can't do anything about it.

```
import 'dart:convert';
import 'dart:collection';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';
import 'package:flutter/rendering.dart';
import 'package:shared_preferences/shared_preferences.dart';


class Home extends StatefulWidget {
 const Home ({key}): super(key: key);

  @override
  State<Home> createState() => _HomeState();
}
  class _HomeState extends State<Home> {

  final myController = TextEditingController();
  bool submit = false;

  Color mainColor = Color(0xFFEEEFF5);
  Color secColor = Color(0xFF3A3A3A);
  Color tdBlue = Color(0xFF5F52EE);


String temp = "";
  List<String> todoList = [];


  @override
  void initState() {

    super.initState();

    myController.addListener(() {
      setState(() {
        submit = myController.text.isNotEmpty;
      });
    });
    
    omLoadData();

  }

  submitData() async {
    setState(() {
      todoList.add(temp);
      clearText();
    });
    SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    await prefs.setStringList('todo_list', todoList);
  }

  omLoadData() async {
    SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    final data = prefs.getStringList("todo_list");
    todoList.addAll(data!);
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    // Clean up the controller when the widget is disposed.
    myController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  void clearText() {
      myController.clear();
  }

     @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context){
   return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: mainColor,
     appBar: AppBar(
       elevation: 0.0,
       backgroundColor: secColor,
      title: Text ('ToDo - List', style: TextStyle(fontSize: 26.5, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, fontStyle: FontStyle.italic),),
     ),
        body: Column(
          children: [
            Container(

              margin: EdgeInsets.only(
                top: 15.0,
                left: 13.0,
                right: 8.0,
              ),
              child: Row(
                children: [
                  Expanded(
                    child: TextField(
                      onChanged: (String value) {
                        temp = value;
                      },

                      controller: myController,
                      decoration:
                      InputDecoration(
                          prefixIcon: Icon(Icons.notes, color: Colors.orangeAccent,),
                          labelText: 'Замітка',
                          hintText: 'Введіть замітку',
                          filled: true,
                          fillColor: Colors.white,
                          border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                          contentPadding: EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
                          enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(30.0),),
                          ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  SizedBox(
                    width: 10.0,
                  ),
                  ElevatedButton(
                    style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(backgroundColor: tdBlue),
                    onPressed:
                    submit ? () => submitData() : null,
                    child:
                    Text('+', style: TextStyle(fontSize: 35),),
                  ),
                ], // Закривається 2-ий чілдрен
              ), //Row 1-ий
            ),

            Expanded(
              child: Padding(
                padding: EdgeInsets.only(
                  top: 5.0,
                ),
                child: ListView.builder(
                    itemCount: todoList.length,
                    itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index){
                      return Dismissible(
                        direction: DismissDirection.endToStart,
                        background: const Card(color: Colors.red,
                        child: Icon(Icons.delete_sweep,size: 30, color: Colors.white,)
                        ),
                        key: Key(todoList[index]),
                        onDismissed: (direction){
                          setState(() async {

                            todoList.removeAt(index);
                          });
                        },
                        child: Card(
                          margin: EdgeInsets.only(
                            top: 8.5,
                            left: 25.0,
                            right: 25.0,
                          ),
                          shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(25.0)),
                          elevation: 0.0,
                          child:
                          ListTile(
                            title: Text(todoList[index],
                            ),),
                        ),

                      );
                    },
                ),
              )

            ),

          ], // Закривається 1-ий чілдрен
        ),
   );
  }

}
```

When deleting a list item with a swipe, it is deleted until I do a Hot restart. When I do a Hot restart the item reappears.Maybe I have a bug in the code. Help me, please.

Comment: that is because you are just removing it from the list and not from the database. remove it from the database and it surely wont comeback

Comment: @john I don't have a database, I have sharedpreferences

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
  submitData() async {
    setState(() {
      todoList.add(temp);
      clearText();
      onSaveData();
    });
  }

  onSaveData()async{
    SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    await prefs.setStringList('todo_list', todoList);
  }
```

Call onSaveData() in onDismissed

```
          onDismissed: (direction) {
            setState(() async {
              todoList.removeAt(index);
              onSaveData();
            });
          },
```

Answer (score 1):

try this on your `onDismissed` method:

```html
 onDismissed: (direction){
                          setState(() async {

                            todoList.removeAt(index);
                               SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
                                prefs.remove(todoList[index]);
                          });
                        },
```

Comment: It doesn't work, I tried many variations, none of them work, maybe the tree is written incorrectly or some bug